# How to install a specific Intel Driver (WIFI) on Ubuntu or other Ubuntu Based Distributions?

Tags: drivers, wireless, intel

I just got a pretty new Notebook (Lenovo T14 AMD), which is equipped with a Intel AX200 Wifi Module.
However this Module has some issues working with older Routers, such as my Easy Box.
The module is correctly recognized and the link speed is normal. A speedtest however is very slow, around 2 Mbit/s.

I was able to solve this issue on windows using the original intel drivers:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/de/download/29520/Windows-10-Gbit-Treiber-f-r-Intel-Wireless-Adapters-?product=189347

The standard windows drivers where pretty slow, same goes for the drivers provided by Lenovo. Only those drivers did the trick.

I also want to use ubuntu/elementaryOS/POP_OS! on this Notebook. However on Ubuntu, I have the same WIFI Speed issues as before on Windows. I assume I need the same original intel drivers on Linux to make it work. Can anyone explain to me how to get them installed on Ubuntu?

Comment: What version Ubuntu?

Comment: Actually I have no preference. I would just use whatever version "works" on this notebook. 18.04 - 20.04
Elementary OS is on 18.04
Pop_OS! is on 20.04